# How to make header and footer inside a form STICKY (i.e. fixed to top and bottom of the form, respectively)?

Tags: html, css

In the following SSCCE,

1. I want to make the `.header` and `.footer` stick to the top and bottom (respectively) of their parent container. So I applied `top:0px` and `bottom:0px` location offsets to them. But this does Not seem to work. The question is WHY and how to achieve what I want?
2. I want to make the `.header` and `.footer` fixed, such that when the content is scrolled, the `.header` and `.footer` don't; they should rather stay FIXED. How do I do that? Applying `position:fixed` is making them stick to the top and botton (respectively) of the entire page (rather than their parent).

```css
body {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.container {
  width: 40%;
  height: 70vh;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 5% auto;
  position: relative;
}
.header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  top: 0px;
  position:absolute;
}
.footer {
  border-top: 1px solid grey;
  bottom: 0px;
  position:absolute;
}
.content {
  padding:20px;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<form class="container">
  <div class="header">I am the header</div>
  <div class="content">I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content. I am the content</div>
  <div class="footer">I am the footer</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `position: absolute` and apply `padding-top` & `padding-bottom` according to the height of the `.header` & `.footer` respectively.

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
body {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.container {
  width: 40%;
  height: 70vh;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 5% auto;
  position: relative;
}
.header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  top: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
}
.footer {
  border-top: 1px solid grey;
  bottom: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
}
.content {
  padding: 20px 0;
  overflow: auto;
  height: calc(100% - 40px); /* 20px for top header & 20px for bottom footer */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">I am the header</div>
  <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate quasi recusandae consequuntur totam obcaecati non, libero nisi a ipsa dolorem, ipsam eveniet reiciendis perferendis quia ut suscipit, nemo, numquam fugiat.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio reprehenderit dolorem harum ipsum, eum, non voluptatem alias voluptatibus voluptatum ullam nostrum deserunt vel doloribus amet eveniet aliquam fugit mollitia quia!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus accusantium laborum hic molestias facere aperiam iste libero non delectus optio cupiditate, officia commodi incidunt odit rem at quo temporibus animi!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam voluptates eius beatae maiores, placeat ad laborum incidunt aliquid, quaerat sed, non molestiae. Ullam sapiente quis cupiditate debitis ducimus perferendis delectus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia quod sit vero provident quaerat a eveniet libero obcaecati iusto temporibus blanditiis minus, non pariatur dolorem minima, sed facilis, corporis cum.</div>
  <div class="footer">I am the footer</div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: hey what if I want to apply the `overflow` property to `.content` instead of the entire `.container`? Why isn't it working (please see Edited code in question)?

Comment: Its my pleasure! @Solace